# masters thesis format for PhD application

Tags: phd, funding, teaching, europe, norway

There is a particular PhD application I am currently applying to a professor but he needs a copy of my masters thesis.
How do I go about uploading? Am I uploading the whole master's thesis as it is, or is there a format I can use to show some specific and important components of the thesis? Please guide me

Comment: Have you asked that professor what they want to see?

Comment: Nobody here is going to know - why don’t you just ask the professor?

Answer (score 1):

If this were my problem, I would hunt down the LaTEX PDF that I created for my thesis, compile the document, save it as "Greathouse_thesis.pdf" and immediately forward it to them.